# jquery code doesnt work on my visual studio ? it works in other editors popperly

Tags: jquery, visual-studio

this is the very simple code I use :
it does work in this editor prpperly :
https://www.javatpoint.com/oprweb/test.jsp?filename=jqueryexample1

(it just doesnt show any thing in VS after running code)

[image]

result after running the code :
[image]

```html
    

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Slider functionality</title>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script>
   
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#slider-1").slider();
           
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- HTML -->
    <div id="slider-1" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in visual studio / (start without debuging )

Comment: code seems to work fine but not in VS , I added the image above right above , thx in advance

Comment: I'n your code you refer to jquery version 1.10.2. In the screenshot you have refered to 3.6.3 ?? 

Also after installing jquery with nuget you still need to refer to the js file

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
to     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>  I did this in code but no change in result @CarstenLøvboAndersen .

Comment: Why download jquery if you refer to online versions? Also what makes you say it aint working? Have you checked console for errors?

Comment: thx for response @CarstenLøvboAndersen , it doesnt show any thing related to jquery code. I added the result image also

Comment: In your browser you need to hit f12 or open the developer tool, to check the console log